# Counter Design using logic circuits

Tags: logic-gates, counter

I want to design a counter using logic circuits... The first counter ic takes it's clk from the frequency circuit... When the first dispay reaches 10.. The other clk should give signal for the second counter to give 1... What happens is that the second display gives 1 when the first is still at 8 so mainly it's 01..02...03...04..05..06..07..18..19..10..11..12..13
Any help?!

[image]

Comment: What is the complete circuit?   That second counter isn't even connected to anything.

Comment: You need to reset the first counter at the same time you increment the second.   The reset pin on the first counter should also be connected to the second counters clock, or something in that direction.

Comment: I tried connecting the clk of the se ond counter to the output of an AND gate between Q1 and Q3 so that it gives 1 when the first wants to reache 10 but as I mentioned it didn't happen and instead it gave 1 when the first was 8

Comment: What Q1 and what Q3?   The schematic is still incomplete.   According to the schematic, it's possible to ASSUME that the display segments are correctly wired and that all chips have power. But there's still nothing that makes U4 count, the first digit should always be zero with this circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The 74160 is decade counter.  You just have to use the RCO (Ripple Carry Out) of the first counter as the clock for the second.

Comment: It works but it gives the signal to the clock at 9 not at 10 so it goes 01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  19  10  11

Answer (score 0):

> Any help?!

start with your display driver. then find a counter that counts to that format.